# Can a graph of a single function $z=f(x,y)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ be compact?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to figure out whether or not any graph of a single function $z=f(x,y)$ can be a compact surface in $\mathbb R^3$, but every example that I come up with seems to be non-compact.
Are there any examples of compact surfaces that are a graph of a single function ?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: What are you assuming about the domain of $f$?

Answer (score 4):

In general, given two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ and a continuous map $f: X \to Y$, then the graph of $f$
$$\Gamma_f := \{(x,y) \in X \times Y \ | \ f(x)=y\}$$
is compact if and only if $X$ is compact.

Indeed, consider the natural maps
$$X \to \Gamma_f; \ x \mapsto (x,f(x)),$$
$$\Gamma_f \to X; \ (x,y) \mapsto x.$$

They are both continuous and surjective, so the claim follows from the fact that the image of a compact space by a continuous map is also compact.

Therefore, in your case a function $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$ defines a compact surface $z=f(x,y)$ if and only if $D$ is compact. In particular, if $D$ is open (for example if you are considering the case where $f$ is smooth), then the the surface $z=f(x,y)$ is never compact.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $$z = \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}$$

Then the graph of it will be a closed hemisphere of unit sphere which clearly compact.

**Remark :** If domain $D$ is not compact then the graph $\Gamma$ cannot be compact. Because the projection $\pi : \Gamma \to D$ and continuous maps take a compact set to compact set.

Comment: Be more specific. The graph of the function on which domain?

Comment: @K.defaoite I've added a remark. I think that it's clear the confusion about the domain.